# selfcrossing.psp with "details" option (as in crossing.psp)

Tags: r, spatstat

I am using

```
xing_points <- crossing.psp(a = x, b = x, details = TRUE) %>% as.data.frame()
```

from the `spatstat` package to obtain all crossing points between segments contained in the `x` dataframe together with the details about where each crossing point comes from.

However, since I use the same dataframe for both `a` and `b` inputs, each crossing point appears twice in the resulting `xing_points` dataframe. It seems natural to me therefore to use the smarter `selfcrossing.psp()` in the following form:

```
xing_points <- selfcrossing.psp(x) %>% as.data.frame()
```

which solves the mentioned issue but, as a matter of fact, lacks the `details` option and, as a consequence, does not allow to track each crossing point back to the original intersecting segments.

How can I achieve the exclusion of repetitions given by the `selfcrossing.psp()` function and the indication of the `details` at the same time?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think it is easiest to use `crossing.psp` and remove the duplicated rows afterwards. To find duplicated rows I use the fact that all columns are numeric so it is possible to sort all the rows and find duplicated rows this way:

```
library(spatstat)
set.seed(123)
x <- psp(runif(10), runif(10), runif(10), runif(10), window=owin())
xing_points <- as.data.frame(crossing.psp(A = x, B = x, details = TRUE))
xing_points <- xing_points[!duplicated(t(apply(xing_points, 1, sort))),]
```

Answer (score 1):

I will take this as a feature request. In a future version of `spatstat`, the function `selfcrossing.psp` will have a `details` argument. [This requires some new C code.] Please watch http://github.com/spatstat/spatstat/releases for updates.

Comment: I appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ege-rubak I came up with a working solution. I could not comment his answer because my response would be too long, so I decided to write an answer to my own question. 
First, I noticed that Ege's solution did not work properly because, due to the algorithm in `crossing.psp`, points of interscetion that have the same `x` and `y` coordinate come from the same couple of instersecting segments but in reverse order. That is, the output of

```
xing_points <- as.data.frame(crossing.psp(A = x, B = x, details = TRUE))
```

will contain, for example, both `iA = 10`, `jB = 6`, and `iA = 6` and `jB = 10`, making the two rows not duplicated.
The solutions I have found is a little more complicated than expected but it worked just fine. It follows:

```
library(spatstat)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
xing_points <- psp(df_select$x_t, df_select$y_t, df_select$x_r, df_select$y_r, owin(), check = F) %>%
  crossing.psp(., ., details = T) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(
    iAjB = iA*jB
  ) %>%
  arrange(x, y, iAjB) %>%
  group_by(iAjB) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

I created the `iAjB` column, then arranged by `x`,`y` and `iAjB`, grouped by the last `iAjB` so that each group contains only the two identical crossing points, and than selected the first point in the group.
Everything seems to work fine now.